# Topology - Prove that a basic neighborhood is not open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be the collection of all functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Given $f\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$, let
$$V(f,\epsilon)=\{g\in X:\ |g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\ \ \forall x\in [0,1]\}$$
Then $\{V(f,\epsilon):\ f\in X,\epsilon>0\}$ form a neighborhood base for a topology $\tau$.

I'm asked to show that $V(f,\epsilon)$ is not open with respect to $\tau$ for every $f\in X$ and every $\epsilon>0$. However, I managed to prove the opposite.

So let $f\in X,\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $g\in V(f,\epsilon)$. By definition, we have $\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Let $\delta=\epsilon-\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|g(x)-f(x)|$. Then $\delta>0$. If $h\in V(g,\delta)$, we have $\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|h(x)-g(x)|<\delta$, from which it follows that
\begin{align*}
\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|h(x)-f(x)|
& \leq \underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|h(x)-g(x)|+\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|g(x)-f(x)| \\
& <\delta+\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|g(x)-f(x)| \\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}
Hence $h\in V(f,\epsilon)$. Since $h$ was arbitrary, we obtain $V(g,\delta)\subseteq V(f,\epsilon)$. In other words, $V(f,\epsilon)$ is open because it contains a basic neighborhood of each point.

Can someone tell me what went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This question seems really weird: by *definition*, the $V(f,\varepsilon)$ are open since they are the building blocks for your topology.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I'm using General Topology by Willard. But he does not require the neighborhoods to be open. 'U is a neighborhood of x in a topological space X iff U contains an open set which contains x. Equivalently, U is a neighborhood of x iff x belongs to the interior of U.'

Comment: Oh I see. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the beginning: if $g \in V(f, \varepsilon)$ this does not mean that the supremum of $\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$ is $< \varepsilon$, it could very well be equal to $\varepsilon$. We’re only given that $\varepsilon$ is an upperbound, so the sup is $\le \varepsilon$.   The given base sets are **not** the open balls in the sup-metric.

Comment: Oh thanks! I forgot that the supremum of a given set need not be an element of that set. But how can I show that the $V(f,\epsilon)$'s are not open in the topology they induce though? To do it directly, we have to find a function $g\in V(f,\epsilon)$ so that every (basic) neighborhood of $g$ contains some function which is not in $V(f,\epsilon)$. I'm just having some trouble achieving this.

Comment: @InTheSea take $f=0$ and \varepsilon=1$. (We only need one example). Can you define a (non-continuous!) $f\in V(0,1)$ where the sup is exactly $1$? Start from that and show no $V(f,\varepsilon)$ sits inside $V(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes. I can take $f$ so that $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1)$ and that $f(1)=0$. Then $|f(x)|<1$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ but $\sup f$ is exactly $1$. Now consider any $t>0$. Without loss of generality, consider only the case when $t<1$. We find a function $g$ such that $|g(x)-f(x)|<t$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ but $|g(a)|\geq 1$ for some $a\in (0,1)$. Let $g=f$ on $[0,1-t/2)\cup (1-t/2,1]$ and let $g(1-t/2)=1$. Then $g$ satisfies the requirements. I think the general case can be dealt with similarly.

Comment: @InTheSea remember, you have to show that your $f$ is not interior. So show that for your $f$ and any $\varepsilon >0$, $V(f, \varepsilon) \nsubseteq V(0,1)$. Then adapt the argument from $V(0,1)$ to any basic subset.